# Positioning entries in a Venn diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I draw a Venn diagram for three sets `A`, `B`, and `C`.  The radius of each circle is `$2\sqrt{2}$`, but I entered it as `2.828` because `TikZ` could not compile my code for the circles - such as `\fill[draw=red] (-2,2) circle (2*sqrt(2));`. How do I enter the radius as `$2\sqrt{2}$`?

The center of `circle A` is (-2,2), the center of `circle B` is (2,2), and the center of `circle C` is (0,-2).  The points at which `circle A` and `circle B` intersect are the origin and (0,4).  I want to place `2`, which represents the number of elements in `A`, `B`, and `C`, on the vertical line between the origin and (0,4).  I use the commands

`\draw[overlay,name path=circle A] (-2,2) circle (2.828);`,

`\draw[overlay,name path=circle B] (2,2) circle (2.828);`,

and

`\path[name intersections={of= circle A and circle B, by=F}];`

to locate one of them.  `TikZ` locates the intersection at (0,4). How do I get `TikZ` to locate both of them and to call one `intersection-AB1` and the other `intersection-AB2`?  Likewise, I would like to call the intersections of `circle B` and `circle C` as `intersection-BC1` and `intersection-BC2`, and I would like to call the intersections of `circle B` and `circle C` as `intersection-AC1` and `intersection-AC2`. I would issue the commands

`\path[name path=lineAB] (intersection-AB1) -- (intersection-AB2);`,

`\path[name path=lineBC] (intersection-BC1) -- (intersection-BC2);`,

and

`\path[name path=lineAC] (intersection-AC1) -- (intersection-AC2);`,

and I would call that intersection `P`, and I would position `2` at `P`.  (I don't want to have `P` in the Venn diagram; I will use it later to draw six other lines. Also, I don't want `2` to be `above right` of the location of point `P`; I want `2` to be typeset at the location of point `P`.)

In my Venn diagram, the number `5`, which represents the number of elements in `A` and `B` that are not in `C`, is to be typeset on the line segment between `intersection-AB1` and `intersection-AB2`. In particular, if I issue the command

`\path[name intersections={of= (intersection-AB1) -- (intersection-AB2) and circle C, by=PC}];`,

I want to have "5" typeset at the location halfway between `PC` and either intersection-AB1 or intersection-AB2 - the one outside circle C.

In my Venn diagram, there are 3 elements in A that are not in either B or C. If, for example, `intersection-BC1` is the intersection of circle B and circle C that is inside circle A, I would like to draw an invisible ray from P through `intersection-BC1` that intersects circle A.  I would call the ray `ray.PA` and I would call the intersection of `ray.PA` and `circle A` the point `intersection-PA` and I would position `3` halfway between `intersection-BC1` and `intersection-PA`.

One last modification to make. I don't want to use `above left` to position `A`.  I want to position the label `A` at an angle of 120 degrees `intersection-PA`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[overlay,name path=circle A] (-2,2) circle (2.828);
\draw[overlay,name path=circle B] (2,2) circle (2.828);
\draw[overlay,name path=circle C] (0,-2) circle (2.828);

\fill[pink!80,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red] (45:2.828) circle (2.828);
\fill[pink!80,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red] (135:2.828) circle (2.828);
\fill[pink!80,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red] (-90:2) circle (2.828);

\path[name intersections={of= circle A and circle B, by=F}];
\path[name intersections={of= circle A and circle C, by=G}];
\path[name intersections={of= circle B and circle C, by=H}];

%This positions a point, called S, halfway between the intersections of circle B and circle C.
\coordinate (S) at ($(G)!0.5!(H)$);
\draw[line width=0.1pt] (G) -- (H);

%This positions a point, called T, halfway between the intersections of circle A and circle C.
\coordinate (T) at ($(F)!0.5!(G)$);
\draw[line width=0.1pt] (F) -- (G);


%The following command puts the number 5 in the region $A \cap B$ and outside the region $A \cap B \cap C$.
\coordinate[label={5}] (A.intersect.B) at (0,2);

%These three rays start at P. They are used to position the names of the sets.
%I have to replace (0,0) with (P).
\path[overlay,name path=node A,blue,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) -- (120:6);
\path[overlay,name path=node B,blue,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) -- (60:6);
\path[overlay,name path=node C,blue,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) -- (-90:5);
\path[name intersections={of= node A and circle A, by=alpha}];
\path[name intersections={of= node B and circle B, by=beta}];
\path[name intersections={of= node C and circle C, by=gamma}];

\coordinate[label={above left:$A$}] (set A) at (alpha);
\coordinate[label={above right:$B$}] (set B) at (beta);
\coordinate[label={below:$C$}] (set C) at (gamma);

%These commands will be deleted. They label various points to more quickly see where the intersections
%F, G, and H are located.

\coordinate[label={above:$F$}] (F) at (F);
\coordinate[label={below left:$G$}] (G) at (G);
\coordinate[label={above right:$H$}] (H) at (H);
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below right:$S$] (S) at (S) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above left:$T$] (T) at (T) {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using `sqrt` use an extra pair of braces

```
\draw[overlay,name path=circle A] (-2,2) circle ({2*sqrt(2)});
```

For second, specify the second intersection point also like

```
\path[name intersections={of= circle A and circle B, by={F,f}}];
```

Drawing those thin lines is up to you as I don't know which points are to be connected.

If I understand the positioning of `5` properly, you need to do this:

```
\draw[line width=0.1pt] (F) -- node{5} (f) ;
```

so that it comes midway between AB1 and AB2.

For that 120 degree query use

```
\coordinate[label={above:$A$}] (set A) at (alpha.120);
```

And again, if I understand properly, this should give you the point `P`:

```
\path[line width=0.1pt,name path=ff] (F) -- node{5} (f) ;

\path[line width=0.1pt,name path=gg] (G) -- (g);
\path[name intersections={of= ff and gg, by=P}];
```

And alas, I am confused reading your question. Here is the possibly incomplete code.  It would have been useful if you provided a complete hand drawn diagram.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[overlay,name path=circle A] (-2,2) circle ({2*sqrt(2)});
\draw[overlay,name path=circle B] (2,2) circle ({2*sqrt(2)});
\draw[overlay,name path=circle C] (0,-2) circle ({2*sqrt(2)});

\fill[pink!80,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red] (45:2.828) circle (2.828);
\fill[pink!80,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red] (135:2.828) circle (2.828);
\fill[pink!80,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red] (-90:2) circle (2.828);

\path[name intersections={of= circle A and circle B, by={F,f}}];
\path[name intersections={of= circle A and circle C, by={G,g}}];
\path[name intersections={of= circle B and circle C, by={H,h}}];

%This positions a point, called S, halfway between the intersections of circle B and circle C.
\coordinate (S) at ($(G)!0.5!(H)$);
\draw[line width=0.1pt] (G) -- (H);
\draw[line width=0.1pt] (g) -- (h);
\draw[line width=0.1pt] (F) -- (g);

%This positions a point, called T, halfway between the intersections of circle A and circle C.
\coordinate (T) at ($(F)!0.5!(G)$);
\draw[line width=0.1pt] (F) -- (G);
\path[line width=0.1pt,name path=ff] (F) -- node{5} (f) ;

\path[line width=0.1pt,name path=gg] (G) -- (g);
\path[name intersections={of= ff and gg, by=P}];

\node at (P) {2};

\draw[name path=PHH] (P) -- ($(P)!6cm!0:(H)$);  Change to `\path`
\path[name intersections={of= PHH and circle A, by=APHH}];
\path (H) -- node{3} (APHH);


%The following command puts the number 5 in the region $A \cap B$ and outside the region $A \cap B \cap C$.
%\coordinate[label={5}] (A.intersect.B) at (0,2);

%These three rays start at P. They are used to position the names of the sets.
%I have to replace (0,0) with (P).
\path[overlay,name path=node A,blue,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) -- (120:6);
\path[overlay,name path=node B,blue,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) -- (60:6);
\path[overlay,name path=node C,blue,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) -- (-90:5);
\path[name intersections={of= node A and circle A, by=alpha}];
\path[name intersections={of= node B and circle B, by=beta}];
\path[name intersections={of= node C and circle C, by=gamma}];

\coordinate[label={above:$A$}] (set A) at (alpha.120);
\coordinate[label={above right:$B$}] (set B) at (beta);
\coordinate[label={below:$C$}] (set C) at (gamma);

%These commands will be deleted. They label various points to more quickly see where the intersections
%F, G, and H are located.

\coordinate[label={above:$F$}] (F) at (F);
\coordinate[label={below left:$G$}] (G) at (G);
\coordinate[label={above right:$H$}] (H) at (H);
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below right:$S$] (S) at (S) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above left:$T$] (T) at (T) {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have been quite helpful.  Thanks.  I am starting to look at your suggestions now.  When I type `\path[name intersections={of= circle A and circle B, by={F,f}}];`, how do I know which will be at the origin and which will be at (0,4)?  Should I just temporarily plot the points?

Comment: I understand your confusion.  I left two line segments in my code but forgot to say "these line segments are misplaced."  I want the location of point `P` to be in the middle of $A \cap B \cap C$.

Comment: @Adelyn The first intersection point will be `F`. Here it is the upper one as you start drawing the circle from right side (angle=0).

Comment: @Adelyn Draw `Ff`  and  `Gg`  Find their intersection for P.

Comment: I see that you edited the code.  Yes, I see that you position `P` in the middle of the intersection of all three sets.

Comment: With just a few minutes, I can label the intersections and find which is `F` and which is `f`.  In case I don't want to take the time, are you saying that since `circle A` precedes `circle B` in the command `\path[name intersections={of= circle A and circle B, by={F,f}}];`, the first intersection will be determined by "following" the the path from its eastern point counterclockwise until it intersects `circle B`.

Comment: I am in New York, and it is 9:40. The coffee bar is closing.  I will look at your comments tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: The number of elements that are in set A but not in sets B or C is 3.  I would like to place "3" in a particular way.  Recall that `P` is the center of the Venn diagram, and `H` is the intersection of `circle B` and `circle C` that is inside `circle A`.  I would like to draw an invisible ray from `P` through `H` until it intersects `circle A`. If this intersection is called (the rather cumbersome) `ray-P-H-circle-A`, "3" is to be placed at the midpoint between H and `ray-P-H-circle-A`.

Comment: @Adelyn Add `\draw[name path=PHH] (P) -- ($(P)!6cm!0:(H)$);
\path[name intersections={of= PHH and circle A, by=APHH}];
\path (H) -- node{3} (APHH);`. Change `\draw` by `\path` to remove the line.

Comment: @Adelyn Did you get the questions answered? If so please consider accepting the answer if you like.

Comment: Sorry.  I will do it presently.